# change the connection string values the app.config

Tags: c#

I am trying to change the connection String values

> connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Tracker;Persist Security Info=false;User ID=sa;Password=p@ssw0rd"

from my user interface. Could any one help to change the settings from the user interface in the windows application?

Comment: You want the application to update it's own app.config file? Rewriting an application's config file from the application itself is not a good idea.

Comment: Seconded.  That's not a good strategy.  If you need to create dynamic connection strings, you probably do not want to store them in the app.config file.  Encrypt to a file or registry is what I'd recommend.

Comment: I just want to change the Data source in the app.config file from the window from. I wanted to take user's input for the data source.

Comment: That is not a good idea. try to store the connection preference in database or in another file.

Comment: i think you need the input for some sort of data migration from one server to another, or something related to this. not sure.. if you want to achive this you can open connection from your code itself.. using `SQLConnection`

Comment: better, store user selected datasource in some user's preference/profile file, and when creating connection sring override datasource value from value in this file

Comment: Should the user be changing the entire connection string (password and all?) or are you trying to hide the user/pwd and just change DataSource?

Comment: @TimMedora: Why do you think it's not a good idea for an application to change its own configuration mechanism (which in this case happens to be an app.config file)? Seems like a totally normal use case to me: The user can configure the behaviour of an application with the application itself.

Answer (score 1):

From the comment thread on the original post, it sounds like the OP needs to enumerate data sources and allow a user to pick one (and perhaps store that preference). Assuming that is the case...

- The actual connection to the database should be secured using integrated Windows security if at all possible. This a [best practice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144228.aspx). Integrated security eliminates the need to store credentials anywhere.
- If the goal is to pick a datasource, it's not hard to list all [databases within an environment](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SubmitSQLInfoEnumerator.aspx) using C#.
- The user's preference/selection should be stored somewhere other than the app.config. The registry, isolated storage, or an XML file are all valid options if no credentials are involved.

Answer (score 1):

> ASP.NET provides the *Web Site Administration Tool* to view and manage the configuration settings for your ASP.NET website. These configuration settings are stored in an xml file called web.config.
>
> ***web.config* is an application configuration file used to define configuration settings such as connecting strings, authentication, authorization etc., for an ASP.NET application**
>
> The tool provides an easy to use interface to edit the configuration settings. However this tool works well when you have to manually make changes. At times, there could be a possibility where we need to make changes to the web.config at runtime. For example: a user requesting to control the connecting string, change session timeouts and so on.
> For this purpose, ASP.NET provides the Configuration API to programmatically manipulate the configuration settings in web.config. The API’s are contained in the *System.Configuration* and *System.Web.Configuration* namespaces. In fact, internally the Web Site Administration Tool uses the same API to edit configuration settings.
> The *WebConfigurationManager* class in the *System.Web.Configuration* namespace is used to create a Configuration object. This object is used to read and write changes to the web.config file. [See](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=102).

See also [Securing Connection Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Let me clarify that this is not what you're asking but by reading this, you will be able to find some clues and come to know what is recommended and what is not.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a Windows application then you don't need to change the app.config file to change the active database connection. I've written about this [on my blog](http://traf-o-data.blogspot.com/2008/11/adaptive-connection-strings-for-windows.html).

Answer (score 0):

User below method to change connection string using C# :

```
public void SaveConnectionString(DbInfo dbinfo, string path,string appConfigFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string configFile = Path.Combine(path, appConfigFile);
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(configFile);
            XmlNodeList endpoints = doc.GetElementsByTagName("connectionStrings");
            foreach (XmlNode item in endpoints)
            {
                if (item.HasChildNodes)
                {
                    foreach (var c in item.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        if (((XmlNode)c).NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                        {


                            var adressAttribute = ((XmlNode)c).Attributes["name"];
                            if (adressAttribute.Value.Contains("YourConStrName"))
                            {
                                if (dbinfo.dbType == dataBaseType.Embedded)
                                {
                                    ((XmlNode)c).Attributes["connectionString"].Value = SetupConstants.DbEmbededConnectionString;
                                    ((XmlNode)c).Attributes["providerName"].Value = SetupConstants.DbEmbededConnectionProvider;
                                }
                                else if (dbinfo.dbType == dataBaseType.Microsoft_SQL_Server)
                                {
                                    if (dbinfo.sqlServerAuthType == SqlServerAuthenticationType.SQL_Server_Authentication)
                                    {
                                       // ((XmlNode)c).Attributes["connectionString"].Value = string.Format(SetupConstants.dbConnStringwithDb, dbinfo.databaseAdress, SetupConstants.SqlDbName, dbinfo.userId, dbinfo.password) + "MultipleActiveResultSets=true;";
                                        ((XmlNode)c).Attributes["connectionString"].Value = string.Format(SetupConstants.dbConnStringwithDb, dbinfo.databaseAdress, dbinfo.DatabaseName, dbinfo.userId, dbinfo.password) + "MultipleActiveResultSets=true;";

                                    }
                                    else if (dbinfo.sqlServerAuthType == SqlServerAuthenticationType.Windows_Authentication)
                                    {
                                        //((XmlNode)c).Attributes["connectionString"].Value = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;", dbinfo.databaseAdress, SetupConstants.SqlDbName);
                                        ((XmlNode)c).Attributes["connectionString"].Value = string.Format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;", dbinfo.databaseAdress, dbinfo.DatabaseName);
                                    }
                                    ((XmlNode)c).Attributes["providerName"].Value = SetupConstants.DbSqlConnectionProvider;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            doc.Save(configFile);
            string exePath = Path.Combine(path, "EDC.Service.exe");
            InstallerHelper.EncryptConnectionString(true, exePath);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //TODO://log here exception
            Helper.WriteLog(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Add bellow class DBinfo

```
public class DbInfo
{
    public DataBaseType dbType { get; set; }
    public SqlServerAuthenticationType sqlServerAuthType { get; set; }
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string databaseAdress { get; set; }
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string password { get; set; }
    public string Port { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseName { get; set; }
}

public enum DataBaseType
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Embedded = 1,
    Microsoft_SQL_Server =2,
}

public enum SqlServerAuthenticationType
{
    Windows_Authentication = 0 ,
    SQL_Server_Authentication =1
}
```